# How can I get SQL Sever Tables to appear in Reverse Engineering Wizard?

Tags: java, sql-server, nhibernate, netbeans

I don't do much Java coding so I am not too familiar with the NetBeans IDE. I am trying to create a reverse engineering file based on a SQL Server connection that is set up in my hibernate.cfg.xml.

The reverse engineering wizard does not show any tables given the configuration file. I do not receive any error however. I believe the configuration is correct. I suspect that I may need to change the database schema. Can anyone tell me what's up or point me to some documentation?

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest trying the Visio reverse engineering feature - it has worked for me in the past.